# Google analytics access to old data

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

We have been using google analytics as our main collection tool since 2016. We accessed the data from regular dashboard and from Chrome add-on via API. Everything worked fine untill the GA has shut down in 2019.

We succesfully migrated all data from 2019 till now to Firebase, but hoped we could save the GA data untouched and analyze it later if needed. Right now this moment has come and I would like to access all historical data from 2016 till 2019.

While trying to do that via API I find that GA interface has completely changed and there is no "View_id" in order to acces it by API. Moreover, GA seems to become a replica of a Firebase data - by that I mean they are linked to the same Firebase datasource.

We would like to assign google analytics interface to the old data from 2016, and we need advice on how to do that. Any other access to old data will do (like transfering to bigquery).
I remember while migrating we marked "save historical data" checkboxes, and it makes me really nervous to think we have lost all our data from 2016 till 2019.

Our account was all the time the same. Main property was called snaappy-chat.

This is how our property looks like now (app + web) type and no views avaliable: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOC7W.png)

I also see that we have intergation with GA enabled in the Firebase console: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPyXc.png)  I really hope that does not delete all the previous data...

Answer (score 0):

For GA4 Properties, you need to use the Google Analytics Data API v1 to access data by an API. See the developer's site: https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data

If you can see your historical data from 2016 to 2019 in the property "snaappy-chat" in Google Analytics, you can use the Data API to create the same reports. See the Data API's schema for a list of dimensions and metrics: https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data/api_schema

App + Web Properties were recently renamed to GA4 Properties. See the blog post: https://blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/new_google_analytics/